# ActiveMQ Artemis: TLS certificate reload

Tags: ssl, certificate, activemq

Can Apache ActiveMQ Artemis (v2.13.0) use an updated TLS certificate while running, or does it require a restart? I did not find something about it in [Configuring Transports](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/configuring-transports.html) and [Configuration Reload](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) sections.

When aiming towards short-living TLS certificates, any restart causes unwanted service interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.10.0 if the keystore and/or truststore are updated at runtime then those changes will be reflected automatically in the broker without requiring a restart. The new values will be applied to *new* connections only. Existing connections will continue to work since they already performed a valid SSL/TLS handshake.

Please note that this behavior changed in the 2.18.0 release due to [an SSL performance issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3117). Instead of updating automatically you'll need to invoke the `reload` operation on the acceptor via [the management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html) (e.g. web console, JMX, HTTP via Jolokia, etc.).

Comment: According to [release notes for v2.18.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2180) and a [performance issue observed with JDK 11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3117) this no longer holds true. Instead, the TLS certificate can be reloaded via JMX.

Comment: @Stephan, that's correct. I'll update my answer.